# Why does my Wordpress site display only blank in IE8 and below?

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

The site in question is [www.dudnyk.com](http://www.dudnyk.com).

It appears fine in every browser, even IE9 but just displays as a completely blank page in IE 8 or 7. I've read about issues about tags that aren't closed but I've double checked. Any ideas? I've also tried deactivating all plug-ins and validating the site to W3.

Comment: You know, there are helpful [validation services](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fdudnyk.com%2f) out there ...

Comment: literally displays a blank page. the source code is all there but the page is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using conditional comments to cater the site content to different IE versions. In this case IE < 9 only sees the opening HTML tag and *nothing else*.

The developer tools were reporting an empty head and body in the DOM, by the way.

Comment: That was exactly it. THANKS. It's so weird because I was using the HTML5 boilerplate and that was included. any reason why that's an issue and they included it?

Comment: It looked like maybe you just deleted something that should still have been there. By the way, if an answer was correct and helpful you can mark it as the *accepted* answer for your question by clicking the hollow checkmark to the left.